# Python - Why ThreadPoolExecutor().submit a thread with queue blocks and Thread().start doesn't?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

> operating system: windows 10
>
> python 3.7.6

1. I have a task function

```py
def mytest(task_queue):
    while True:
        print(task_queue.get())
```

2. I want run sub thread and waiting for others put something into `task_queue`.
3. If I use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor().submit()` start thread, then put something into queue, it will block, `task_queue.put(1)` never run.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import queue
    task_queue = queue.Queue()
    task_queue.put(0)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.submit(mytest, task_queue)
    task_queue.put(1)
    task_queue.put(2)
# only print 0, then block
```

4. If I start thread by `Thread().start()`, it works as I expect.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import queue
    task_queue = queue.Queue()
    task_queue.put(0)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=mytest, args=(task_queue,))
    t1.start()
    task_queue.put(1)
    task_queue.put(2)
# print 0, 1, 2. but the main thread does not exit
```

5. But I don't think either of these methods will block the code because they just start the thread.
6. So I have 2 question:

   - Why does `submit()` block the code?
   - Why main thread does not exit when use `start()` to start sub thread without `join()`?

THX

Answer (score 2):

Q-1) Why does `submit()` block the code?

A-1) No `submit()` method not blocking, it is schedules the callable `mytest` to be executed as `mytest(task_queue)` and returns a [Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) object.  Look at below code, you will see that `submit()` method will not block the main thread

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import queue
    task_queue = queue.Queue()
    task_queue.put(0)
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    executor.submit(mytest, task_queue)
    task_queue.put(1)
    task_queue.put(2)


print("hello")

>> 0
   hello
   1
   2
```

Or you can do like :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import queue
    task_queue = queue.Queue()
    task_queue.put(0)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.submit(mytest, task_queue)
        task_queue.put(1)
        task_queue.put(2)
```

You will see that `task_queue.put(1)` and other will be called immediately

As you see above examples, `submit()` method not blocking, but when you use `with` statement with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()`, `__exit__()` method will be called end of the `with` statement. This `__exit__()` method will call `shutdown(wait=True)` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) of `ThreadPoolExecutor()` class. When we look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) about `shutdown(wait=True)` method :

> If wait is True then this method will not return until all the pending
> futures are done executing and the resources associated with the
> executor have been freed. If wait is False then this method will
> return immediately and the resources associated with the executor will
> be freed when all pending futures are done executing. Regardless of
> the value of wait, the entire Python program will not exit until all
> pending futures are done executing.

That's why your main thread blocked end of the `with` statement.

I want to give an answer to your second question, but i am confused with something about main thread exit or not. I will edit this answer later (for second question)

Comment: Thans for your answer. This does solve the Q1. And I seem to have found the answer to the Q2. According to [python doc - Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), `The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.`, and `mytest` thread is not a daemon thread. I misunderstood `join()`, it just waits for the sub thread to finish excuting, instead of avoiding the main thread exiting. If I set `t1` to daemon by `t1 = threading.Thread(target=mytest, args=(task_queue,), daemon=True), the main thread will exit immediately.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread(...).start()` creates a new thread. End of story. You can always create a new thread if there's still some memory left in which to create it.

`executor.submit(mytest, task_queue)` creates a new *task* and adds it to the `task_queue`. But adding the task to the queue will force the caller to wait until there is room for it in the queue.

Some time later, when the task eventually reaches the head of the queue, a worker thread will take the task and execute it.